# Excel - Return other values based on grabbed value

Tags: excel

I have two tables that are to display part quotes by 1. lowest cost, and 2. lowest lead time. These tables scan across all sheets (each one being vendor specifically) to find these values.

I was able to find the lowest lead time and cost using the following function :

```
=SMALL('Summary:Vendor Template'!I24,1)
```

But now I'm trying to use the INDEX function to return the name of the vendor back to a neighboring cell.

Currently what I have in the cell where this should be present is:

```
=INDEX('Summary:Vendor Template'!C25,MATCH(I25,'Summary:Vendor Template'!I25,0))
```

I25 being where the costs are located across all pages and C25 being where the Vendor name should return. Instead, I get #VALUE, so I'm guessing my syntax isn't quite right.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is an example.

I have 4 sheets currently; Summary, Test1, Test2, and Vendor Template.

Below is an example of the table on Test1

| no. | p/n | vendor | descrip | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 223 | test1 | screw | 150 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Below is an example of the table on Test2

| no. | p/n | vendor | descrip | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 223 | test2 | screw | 110 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Here is the table on the summary page where the lowest price of the 223 Screw should be presented.

| no. | p/n | vendor | descrip | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | 110 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

The Small function returned the 110 value, but now my goal is to use the Index Match combination to return which vendor that value corresponds to.

Comment: Please provide sample data in markdown format and expected output. Check the following resources: 1) [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 2) [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)

Comment: The sample data and output have been added.